# Use the MVT for Integrals to bound $\int_0^1\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, mean-value-theorem

I have an exercise to use the mean value theorem for integrals to show that

$$\frac{1}{7\sqrt 2}\le\int_0^1\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx\le\frac{1}7$$

I've determined that the integrand is increasing on the given interval and therefore minimized at $x=0$ and maximized at $x=1$.

By the integral MVT there exists some point $c\in [0,1]$ such that

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\ dx = f(c)(1-0) = f(c)$$

Since $0\le f(c)\le 1/\sqrt 2$ I get a bound but not as tight as the one requested.

But at this point I'm not sure where a factor of 7 comes from.  I could guess that I should start actually integrating some stuff but then that seems like I'm not using the integral MVT as instructed.

If I tried doing just a little, I could set $u=1+x^2$ so that the integral becomes

$$\int_1^{2}\frac{x^6}{u^{1/2}} \left(\frac{du}{2x^2}\right) = \frac 1 2 \int_1^2 \frac{x^4\ du}{u^{1/2}} = \frac 1 2 \int_1^2\frac{(u-1)^2\ du}{u^{1/2}}$$

But like ... now I'm just computing the integral.

Comment: I don't get why the MVT is even required, you just require that $$ 
\frac{x^6}{\sqrt{2}} \leq \frac{x^6}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \leq x^6 \quad \text{for all } x \in [0,1].
$$
That makes me feel like the question is off, use a strong result to obtain a really weak one? Weird.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I assume this is supposed to just be some excuse to exercise the MVT in order to get familiar with it.  I mean if you can solve it with elementary methods and a small number of steps, then it can't be that the MVT is somehow essential here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ and $g(x)=x^6$. Then,
$$\int_0^1f(x)g(x)dx=c\int_0^1g(x)dx$$
were $c\in[\min f([0,1]),\max f([0,1])]=[1/\sqrt2,1]$.

Comment: Nevertheless, I agree with @SarveshRavichandranIyer's comment.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the integral MVT, this looks more like the order-preserving property of integration, that if $f\le g$ then $\int f\le \int g$.  But maybe I'm just misunderstanding the logic.

Comment: This is the first integral MVT, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals, but the main tool to prove it is indeed the order-preserving property of $\int$, and actually that tool (without MVT) is sufficient here, as commented by SarveshRavichandranIyer

Comment: $+1,$ This answer must be the answer the question-asker was looking for and it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, I didn't realize there were two versions of the theorem.  Yep, this makes perfect sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By MVT, we have some $c\in (0,1)$ such that

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} d x =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}} \int_0^1 x^n d x  =\frac{1}{(n+1) \sqrt{1+c^2}}
$$
Meanwhile,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{1}=1 \\
\Rightarrow & \frac{1}{(n+1)\sqrt{2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{(n+1) \sqrt{1+c^2}} \leqslant \frac{1}{n+1} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence, in general,$$
\boxed{\frac{1}{(n+1) \sqrt{2}} \leqslant \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} d x \leqslant \frac{1}{n+1}}
$$

Comment: The answer by Anne is already enough for me -- but I will say, it seems like your solution could replace 7 with any arbitrarily large number, like $10^{10^{10}}$.